# Convolution of two Uniformly distributed r.v. ove

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Assume a continuous random variable $X$ that is uniformly distributed $\underline{\text{on}}$ a $k$-sphere. For simplicity, lets assume a simple circle with radius $R$ in 2 dimension. Therefore
$$f(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi R}, \;\;\;r=R$$
 Assume $Y$ is another random variable identical to $X$

Can someone please help me to derive the probability density function (pdf) of $Z=X+Y$?

Comment: u can go fr geometric probability approach..

Comment: Use the ton of symmetry in the problem.

Comment: would you please explain more

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of "Therefore
$f(r)=\frac{1}{2\pi R}, \;\;\;r=R$ 
and $0$ elsewhere." If ever $f$ is referring to a density, this is unfortunate since there is no density (with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^2$) here. Otherwise, please explain.

Comment: @Did assume a circle with radius $R$. It has area $2\pi R$ and $f(r)=\frac{1}{2\pi R}$. It is equivalent to uniform distribution. the $$\text{Prob}(a <\theta< b|R) =\int_a^b f(r)\mathrm{d}\theta =\int_a^b R\frac{1}{2\pi R}\mathrm{d}\theta $$. I just noticed that I have not mentioned $0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$

Comment: In last comment I meant "circumference" not "area"

Comment: So... $f(r)$ is referring to the density of the argument $\theta$ of $X$ on the circle, right? No clue why you denote this by $f(r)$ and why you add "$r=R$ and $0$ elsewhere" then.

Comment: @Did I wrote the question with an eye on convolution of two random variables. I agree that there is ambiguity on the way I have written. I will explain why I was concerned about $r$. As far as I could solve this problem, the convolution of two circle consists of two circles at $r=R$ that caries $1/2$ of the CDF. Also, $1/4$ of the CDF is distributed uniformly on the circumference of a circle with $r=2R$. The rest of the CDF ($1/4$) is a Dirac delta function centred in origin. As you see, the pdf of sum depends on $r$ and not on $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

In dimension two, one considers some i.i.d. random variables $X$ and $Y$ and it seems that each is uniformly distributed on the *circle* $\{(u,v)\mid u^2+v^2=1\}$ (this assumes without loss of generality that $R$ in the post is $R=1$). (Note in particular that $X$ and $Y$ have no density.) The distribution of $Z=X+Y$ is invariant by the rotations centered at the origin and is concentrated on the *disk*  $\{(u,v)\mid u^2+v^2\leqslant2\}$. Thus, for every $r$, 
$$
P(\|Z\|\geqslant r)=P(\|Z\|^2\geqslant r^2)=P((1+\cos\alpha)^2+(\sin\alpha)^2\geqslant r^2),
$$
where $\alpha$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,2\pi)$ or, equivalently, on $(0,\pi)$. Furthermore, $(1+\cos\alpha)^2+(\sin\alpha)^2=2(1+\cos\alpha)$ hence
$$
P(\|Z\|\geqslant r)=P\left(\cos\alpha\geqslant\frac12r^2-1\right)=\frac1\pi\arccos\left(\frac12r^2-1\right).
$$
Differentiating this and using the fact that $(\arccos)'(x)=1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$, one gets the density of $\|Z\|$ and finally that $Z=(R\cos\Theta,R\sin\Theta)$ where $(R,\Theta)$ has density
$$
f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta)=\frac{2\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt r\lt2}}{\pi\sqrt{4-r^2}}\cdot\frac{\mathbf 1_{(0,2\pi)}(\theta)}{2\pi}.
$$

Comment: I think I have asked question not very clearly. I mean that $X$ is a uniform distribution on the circumference of a circle with radius $R$. So the P$(a<X<b) = \frac{b-a}{2\pi R}$. Assume $Y$ is another independent random variable identical to $X$. I am trying to get the pdf of $Z=X+Y$.

Comment: And X and Y uniformly distributed on a circle is exactly the situation my answer deals with. What do you mean by "a<X<b"? If a, X and b are on a circle, they cannot be compared...